# Least overkill solution to transmit single bit wirelessly

Tags: rf, wireless

I am looking for suggestions to transmit just a single bit wirelessly, through walls (limestone) and at a range of ~30-50 ft.  The purpose is a simple motion detector which produces a status bit and I want to a couple of these located in different places.

Bluetooth seems like overkill to me.  I really just need a very low power solution; cheap would be nice too.  I am also avoiding any MCU.

Comment: why does having an MCU mean overkill to you? It's significantly easier to implement logic on an MCU than dealing with digital logic gates. Also, designing your own wireless protocol which is robust enough against external noise is way overkill vs. using a pre-designed bluetooth module.

Comment: I am not looking to design a wireless protocol; I am just ignorant of what options there are other than bluetooth, IR (no LOS in this case), RF. And I don't have much logic to implement, it's literally a 0 or a 1.  Bluetooth can send video and audio at high rate; this is unnecessary to me. A MCU requires programming and in general more power than not.  This will be outside and so I am trying to limit the 'moving parts' that could break.  If bluetooth is necessary though I can go down that road.

Comment: Carrier pigeon. Send a white scrap of paper for "0", and a black scrap of paper for "1".

Comment: You could look at X10 (very old-school, but it sounds like you're looking for something old-school). Here is a motion sensor that sounds like what you want: http://www.walmart.com/ip/X10-EagleEye-Wireless-Indoor-Outdoor-Motion-Sensor-MS16A/33950811?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=443&adid=22222222227022683058&wmlspartner=wmtlabs&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=98281122634&wl4=pla-225991964434&wl5=9031195&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=111830448&wl11=online&wl12=33950811&wl13=&veh=sem     (I use to get them for $9).

Comment: Keep in mind that, if the application is security, you need a protocol that acknowledges when the "bit" is correctly received. Many times a transmission doesn't get through, and the sender needs to know whether to resend (X10 suffers from this shortcoming).

Comment: The security is for dumb muggers or burglars.  If someone who knows how to hack my wireless signal comes for me, I'm already fkud

Comment: Too many restrictions make this a pointless question. You are missing the subtleties of radio transmission with the belief that you can avoid an MCU. This is foolish.

Comment: Another user posted the 433 MHz TX/RX pair.  This looks like there is no MCU; am I missing something?  I also said I am avoiding it, not ruling it out.  Jesus there are some persnickety people on here; who will complain yet provide no information.

Comment: @Andy aka: Then how do my car keys and garage door get away without an MCU?  Why would they do this (maybe power, area, or cost)?  I guess the designers there are missing the subtleties of radio transmission? Or maybe you are missing some subtleties of design if you arbitrarily insist on implementing every solution with a MCU?

Comment: @jbord39 - if you can show me a schematic of a car key that uses something else to generate a preamble, then a high integrity address followed by a status byte followed by an error check code then I'll remove my comments and take up a course in understanding radios better. On the other hand, don't bother because I'm not bothered about giving you help.

Comment: @Andy aka: The keys for my 2004 Pontiac Grand Prix or any garage door opener.  And no, clearly you have not been bothered to provide any help.  You have instead crapped on the question instead of giving any reasonable response.  You didn't even make a case for the MCU, just prattled off your knowledge of radio transmission which is irrelevant to this question.  You seem ignorant and hostile?  What is wrong with the 433MHz Tx/Rx combo that tcrosley mentioned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42211/discussion-between-jbord39-and-andy-aka).

Comment: In actuality, a garage or car type remote control, and especially one implementing security is going to use either an MCU or dedicated logic of nearly comparable complexity.  More than a few special function chips are actually MCUs that are either pre-programmed or mask-programmed to do that job, with data sheets that describe *what* they do rather than *how* the are structured internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple 433 MHz transmitter receiver pair like this one [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008A4UWK6) for $5.  It's says it's designed for a burglar alarm but that just means it works with an on/off signal.  Like older garage door openers before they added the digital encryption.

They don't give a range but for $5 you can afford to experiment.  The bigger the antenna, the better, but one of the commenters recommends a 20 cm simple wire.

[image]

There are lots of similar products; just search for 433 MHz.

Comment: No, simple OOK radios like this will not be reliable without something more sophisticated to distinguish valid data from noise.      While that can be done with a special function IC, or with analog circuitry, often the *available on-hand*, familiar, and (at least in small quantity) most cost-effective solution is to use an MCU.  And the special function IC may in fact be a small MCU with a mask program.  However if the application can tolerate failures and false readings, using the modules bare might sort of work.